change OTLPTraceExporter URL every time new request arrive to web app
I want to replace OTLPTraceExporter URL every time my web app receive a new request. Is this even possible?.
My current instrumentation file looks like this:


async function getTracer(nameWorkflow, jeagerEndpoint) {
    const sdk = new NodeSDK({
        serviceName: `${nameWorkflow}`,
        SEMRESATTRS_SERVICE_VERSION: '1.0.0',
        spanProcessor: new SimpleSpanProcessor(new OTLPTraceExporter({
            url: jeagerEndpoint
        })),
        resourceDetectors: [
            envDetector, hostDetector, osDetector, processDetector
        ],
        textMapPropagator: new B3Propagator()
    });
    sdk.start();
    return { tracer: trace.getTracer(`${nameWorkflow}_default`), sdk: sdk };
};



This is how I do start my traces and after I send the response of my function I stop my sdk so I can restart it with new endpoint:


const objectTelemetry = await getTracer(msg.data.workflowName + "Service_Name", msg.data.JEAGER_ENPOINT);
//Example of how I do create my spans.
const spanTransformation = tracer.startSpan('Service_Name', {}, activeContext);
spanTransformation.setAttribute('Service_Name', result);
spanTransformation.end();
//I stop my current sdk so I can restart it after service receive new request.
objectTelemetry.sdk.shutdown();



This works first time then I get this error for trace and context: Error: @opentelemetry/api: Attempted duplicate registration of API: trace
The more I read on docs the more I think is not really possible to do it. Please if there is away could you point to me where I could search for something similar.

You can implement your own OTLPTraceExporter sub-class that can accept multiple URLs and then export to whichever URL you want by overriding the export method: https://open-telemetry.github.io/opentelemetry-js/classes/_opentelemetry_otlp_exporter_base.OTLPExporterBase.html
